# ahref - hide selection color

Tags: html, css, href

I am using a bit of HTML in my IPhone application. I don't have much idea about HTML.
When we touch any hyperlink(ahref in HTML) there is a blue selection color that appears in "li" which contains ahref. How can we disable it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the behaviour by specifying your custom color for links via css:

```
a { color:green; }
```

Or based on their status eg active, clicked, etc:

```
a:active { color:green; }
a:visited { color:red; }
a:hover { color:orange; }
```

Comment: Thanks...Not exactly what you said but it really helped me to figure out the solution. Solution is : .content ul li a:active {
    background: transperent;
}

Comment: I am putting another question on Stack Overflow. May be you can help me in that too.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure, but if the text is truly being selected, and you're seeing a blue color, then the fix would be to apply a style like this:

```
li::selection {
  background-color: transparent;
}
li::-webkit-selection {
  background-color: transparent;
}
li::-moz-selection {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

That's only if it truly is a selection that's occuring. Mind you, only the `::selection` and maybe the `:-webkit-selection` could possibly apply to an iPhone. `::-moz-selection` would be for a Firefox browser.